# Testing onPause() , onDestroy() using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

How can I use Robotium to verify that my Activity handles `onPause()`, `onDestroy()`, `onResume()` and similar calls correctly?

In my Robotium test I can call stuff like

```
solo.getCurrentActivity().onKeyDown(0, null);
```

but how can I simulate an activity being destroyed and recreated?  I don't see any

```
solo.getCurrentActivity().onPause()
```

or

```
solo.getCurrentActivity().onDestroy()
```

methods that I can use?
Is this not what Robotium is designed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a test case base class that has access to `Instumentation` and then use [Instrumentation#callActivityOnPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#callActivityOnPause%28android.app.Activity%29) and [Instrumentation#callActivityOnDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#callActivityOnDestroy%28android.app.Activity%29).

Answer (score 1):

This will destroy your activity and create a new one:

```
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.recreate();
        }
    });
    setActivity(null);
    activity = getActivity();
```

This only works on API 11 and up due to the call to "activity.recreate()". If you don't care about saving / restoring instance state in this test, you could call "activity.finish()" instead, which is available on all versions.